# ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

When trying to deploy app after first time failure due to default network unavailability

```
(py3.9.0) C:\Data\Rapid\GCP\gcloud_SDK\appengine\flexible\flex_and_vision>gcloud app deploy

ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
This may be due to network connectivity issues. Please check your network settings, and the status of the service you are trying to reach.
```

**app.yaml**

```
service: face-detect
network:
  name: sap-lds-vpc
  subnetwork_name: sap-lds-public-subnet-1
runtime: python
env: flex
automatic_scaling:
   min_num_instances: 2
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3

env_variables:
  CLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET: prj-rapid-env-1172020
```

Comment: Without details about your system, software configurations, network, etc., my guess is that you have an Antivirus program interfering with connections created by the CLI, you have an unstable Internet connection or you have a faulty deployment script. Edit your question with more details about your setup. Also include your App Engine deployment files.

Comment: Do you face the same issue with helloWorld app? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/quickstart

Comment: helloWorld app (flexible) is perfectly deployed. however I am unable to deploy the following app

python-docs-samples/codelabs/flex_and_vision

I have created storage bucket and mentioned same in app.yaml file. The account I am using this is my owner account.

Comment: {\"ResourceType\":\"compute.beta.regionAutoscaler\",\"ResourceErrorCode\":\"403\",\"ResourceErrorMessage\":{\"code\":403,\"message\":\"The caller does not have permission\",\"status\":\"PERMISSION_DENIED\",\"statusMessage\":\"Forbidden\",\"requestPath\":\"

Comment: Please create new question with it, as this is different error and it could be confusing